# Parameter fitting

Tags: python, parameters, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize

I wrote the following code in order to fit the parameters K and c of the given below equation based on the last row of data provided. However, the parameters returned by the optimization when put back in the equation do not give the same result for the equation (should be 0.1 but I'm getting 0.99) How can I re-adjust the code so that it fits the parameters to make the function equal to 0.1 based on the given value ranges of P and N?

```
#import numpy as np
#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit # this guy will help us fit everything

def func(K, N, P, c):
    return K * N * P**c

# Arrays we want to fit
P_array = [4.9, 3.9, 3.5, 2.6, 2.0]
N_array = [0.4, 0.7, 1.5, 2.8, 7]

#run the curve fitting:
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, P_array, N_array)

print('our parameter K = {0}, c = {1}'.format(popt[0], popt[1]))
K = popt[0]
c = popt[1]

result = func(K, N_array[0], P_array[0], c)
print('result based on calculated parameters = {0}'.format(result))
```

our parameter K = 0.6543608665770835, c = 0.8426663272072936
result based on calculated parameters = 0.99880867573

[image: Data Provided]

[image: Equation used to define func]

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding in how curve fitting generally works. You have to formulate the problem firtst correctly for `curve_fit`. What I mean is that you need to have problem with form `ydata = func(xdata, *params)` and then identify which is `xdata`, which is `ydata` and which  are `params`

Comment: Also, the question how to identify your `xdata`, `ydata`, etc. is offtopic on SO and more on topic in https://stats.stackexchange.com/ or https://datascience.stackexchange.com/